# How can use overload in xhtml file

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces-3

In my Icefaces3 Application I have Manage bean ancestor that defines common attributes including CSS to be apply because the icons on menu change depending on which is selected. The managed bean them define the style to be applied to these icons. How can I map this in the XHTML file?

CommonMBean.java :

```
package com.omb.view;

public class CommonMBean 

    private String menu1Css = "";
    private String menu2Css = "";


    public String getMenu1Css() {
        return this.menu1Css;
    }

    public void setMenu1kCss(String menu1Css) {
        this.menu1Css = menu1Css;
    }

    public String getMenu2Css() {
        return this.menu2Css;
    }

    public void setMenu2Css(String menu2Css) {
        this.menu2Css = menu2Css;
    }
}
```

FirstMBean.java :

```
package com.omb.view;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.accor.gestpro.view.AbstractBackingBean;

@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class FirstMBean extends CommonMBean {

    public String displayMenu1() {
        setMenu1Css("menu1Sel");
        setMenu2Css("menu2");
        return "menu1";
    }

}
```

SecondeMBean.java :

```
package com.omb.view;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.accor.gestpro.view.AbstractBackingBean;

@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class SecondeMBean extends CommonMBean {

    public String displayMenu2() {
        setMenu1Css("menu1");
        setMenu2Css("menu2Sel");
        return "menu2";
    }

}
```

XHTML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<body>
    <ui:composition>
        <ice:form id="buttonsForm" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
            xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

            <ul class="mainMenu">
                <li class="home"><ice:commandLink
                        **styleClass="#{firstMBean.menu1Css}"** value="Menu 1"
                        action="#{firstMBean.displayMenu1}" /></li>
                <li class="activity"><ice:commandLink
                        **styleClass="#{secondeMBean.menu2Css}"**
                        value="Menu 2"
                        action="#{secondeMBean.displayMenu2}" />
            </ul>
        </ice:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

what does i do here : styleClass="???" :

Comment: An expression in form of Expression Language maybe? What have you tried?

Comment: I have an EL with styleClass="#{firstMBean.menu1Css}" and styleClass="#{secondeMBean.menu2Css}". But It's not good beacause the session scope.

Comment: Then your real problem is about the scope of your beans.

Comment: No, I would like to know what I should use to EL overload? styleClass = "# {} commonMBean.menu1Css"? I would use the getter / setter current mbean in session.